# REST API POST multipart/form-data

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I've got the following call successfully done in POSTMAN using the **form-data**:
[image: Postman payload request]

I am trying to replicate this to an SSJS script but I am having an error : **BAD REQUEST**,

```
<script runat=server>
Platform.Load("core", "1.1.1");

var apiKey = '34b7dffb-ace3-46e2-a95b...'
var url = 'https://acwebtest.cruisetraka.com/guestdocument/'

var payload = {
            "ClientId":'133786...',
            "ResId":'20354...',
            "CruiseCode":'AA210...'
        };
    
  var req = new Script.Util.HttpRequest(url);
  req.emptyContentHandling = 0;
  req.retries = 2;
  req.continueOnError = true;
  req.contentType = 'multipart/form-data'
  req.setHeader('api-key', apiKey);
  req.method = 'POST';
  req.postData = Stringify(payload);

  var resp = req.send();
  Platform.Response.Write("</br> response: " + String(resp.content));
  var resultJSON = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(String(resp.content));
  Platform.Response.Write("</br> resultJSON: " + resultJSON);

</script>
```

Comment: Can you try the JSON format in the postman and see if that is working or not? Also is there any other error you see? Try publishing it on a Cloud page. Also use TRY and Catch

https://code4.cloud/articles/sfmc-error-handling-with-try-catch-in-ssjs-and-ampscript/

https://mateuszdabrowski.pl/docs/ssjs/debugging-ssjs/

Comment: I think I answered your question here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/269315/integrating-an-external-form-with-marketing-cloud-using-cloudpages-and-ssjs/269820#269820

Comment: Is the endpoint expecting "multipart/form-data" or "application/json" as the content type of your post. JSON doesn't look anything like the payload of "multipart/form-data".

Comment: Hi @Macca the endpoint is expecting multipart/form-data

Comment: @YashasviPandey yes, the response in cloud page is Bad request

Comment: @JonasLamberty thank you let me try this.

Comment: @CAR multipart/form-data payloads contain boundaries to define the different mime types being posted. You define the boundary string in the header. Here is an example in SSJS https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/315887/posting-multipart-form-data-payloads-with-ssjs. The payload is not JSON, but rather key values. Here's a useful article that does a good job of describing the type of payload you're trying to put together in SSJS https://roytuts.com/boundary-in-multipart-form-data/